# How to compile a Zend extension that does not depend on different versions of API?

Tags: php, php-extension

When I try to run a zend extension compiled with PHP version 7.2 on an environment with PHP version 7.0, I get the following error:

```
Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20170718
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
```

How can I create the extension so that it works on the different versions of PHP, especially for all the 7.x versions?
Is there a way to ignore this check or any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - **NO**, you will need to compile it using the correct version.

Seen this a number of times.

First step is to download your .tar.gz extension source code then unzip it with tar -zxvf file.tar.gz and change into the folder.

Bring up a web page displaying your servers php.ini. You are looking for the version of PHP API, and the extension_dir.

In your terminal, cd into the module source code folder, and type `phpize`.

If when you check the API versions , they are different from your php.ini, then an old version of php is being used in the terminal, and your module will not work! In this case, you need to get it to use the correct phpize.

type `which phpize` to find out where the offending file is. (mine was /usr/bin/phpize)

My PHP appeared to be in `/usr/local`, so I tried running `/usr/local/phpize`. The API’s matched. So then I did the following:

```
mv /usr/bin/phpize /usr/bin/phpize-old
ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpize /usr/bin/phpize
```

Half way there! We need to do the same for `php-config`

```
mv /usr/bin/php-config /usr/bin/php-config-old
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php-config /usr/bin/php-config
```

Now you have done that, installation should be trivial, and work as per loads of tutorial/instruction pages on the web.

```
./configure
 make
 make install
```

Finally edit your php.ini and add ‘extension = memcached.so’ (or whatever module you compiled), and restart your apache server!

One last thing. ou may need to run `phpize –clean` if it is still compiling with the older stuff from within the modules source folder.

Hope this helps! Here's my original blog post on the matter https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/manually-compiling-php-modules-successfully/

Comment: Well, that's technically not what he asked for. He didn't ask "how to compile an extension", but if it was possible to compile an extension that will work with all 7.* PHP versions. Besided that, I did this recently and I've to say this is a well documented answer!

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks, also, could you tell me if only same major version is required or issue is there with each minor version as well?